# VB.Net: Crystal Report shows different results when run

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I created crystal report in VB.Net... When I clicked report preview, it shows correct result...

When I run the program, at first click of print, it will shows different result, I have to click other reports then go back to the one i want to print to see the correct output...

In the crystal report i have 3 groups and a subreport in the last group...

What do you think is the problem? Please help! God bless :D

Comment: how can we help you if you don't post some codes? or even screenshots. :D

Comment: as you can see... i don't have enough point to post picture.. :)

Comment: you can now post picture on your question :)

Comment: Filipino ka pala @johnwoo :) got it na... thanks ha! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is "`Save Data With Report`" in report designer checked?
[the flag is visible when you see report preview in designer]

This flag causes unexpected behaviours (and many headaches to me).